# Why it doesn't work? If instruction in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have problem with my script. I don't know how to fix it.

```
location=$(locate wpa_supplicant | sed -n '2p')
x=$(ls -l /etc | grep "su" | sort | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f13)
y=$(du -h $location)

a=$(test -f $location)
b=$(test -b $location)

if [ $a = 0 ] || [ $b = 0 ]; then
    echo "This is file"
else
    echo "This is not file"
fi
```

I launched this script and I got error:

> ./ko.ssh: line 18: [: =: unary operator expected
>
> ./ko.ssh: line 18: [: =: unary operator expected

What is wrong?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `$a` and `$b` are empty. Therefore, what the shell gets is

```
if [ = 0 ] || [ = 0 ]
```

which produces the error you encountered. Double quote the variables

```
[ "$a" = 0 ]
```

to make the shell see

```
if [ "" = 0 ]
```

The reason why both the variables are empty is the assignment

```
a=$(test -f $location)
```

`$(...)` is command substitution, it returns the output of the enclosed command. But `test` doesn't output anything, you are interested in its return value instead.

```
test -f $location
a=$?
test -b $location
b=$?
```

Or use the conditions directly

```
if [ -f "$location" ] || [ -b "$location" ] ; then
```

Note the double quotes!

If you're using bash and don't care about portability to other shells, you can switch to double square brackets which don't need the quotes and can handle the logical operators themselves:

```
if [[ -f $location || -b $location ]] ; then
```